# invalid host in upstream NginX when used path in upstream

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

```
upstream backend {
  server domain1.com/path1;
  server domain2.com/path/path2;
  server domain3.com/pah3;
}
location @ {
  proxy_pass https://backend;
  proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/sslcerts/backend.server.pem;
  proxy_ssl_verify              off;
}
```

was trying to load balance traffic to all servers in backend, getting error as `invalid host in upstream`  is there any other way to configure nginX to meet this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstream does not take paths.
Don't know why you're using a named location here (@)?!

```
upstream backend {
  server domain1.com;
  server domain2.com;
  server domain3.com;
}
location / {
  proxy_pass https://backend/path1;
  proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/sslcerts/backend.server.pem;
  proxy_ssl_verify              off;
}
```

You have to use the same path on the backends or at least forward from this path to the right one..

If you rely on different paths and you can't touch the backend servers try this (hacky) work-around:

```
upsteam virtualloadbalancer {
    server 127.0.1.1;
    server 127.0.1.2;
    server 127.0.1.3;
}

server {
    listen 127.0.1.1;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://domain1.com/path1;
    }
}

server {
    listen 127.0.1.2;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://domain2.com/path2/path;
    }
}
server {
    listen 127.0.1.3;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://domain3.com/path3;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://virtualloadbalancer;
        proxy_next_upstream error | timeout | invalid_header | http_500 | http_502 | http_503 | http_504 | http_403 | http_404 | http_429
    }
}
```

Comment: what could be a feasible solution to achieve this requirement, where i have multiple backends with different path and domains,

Comment: Edited, please try (have no time for trying) and comment (or upvote if working) :)

Comment: thank you for the workaround, its working